# Find the probability that not all the targets in the group will be detected.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> > There is group of $k$ targets, each of which independently of other targets, can be detected by a radar unit with probability $p$. Each of $m$ radar units detects the targets independently of other units. Find the probability that not all the targets in the group will be detected.

**My Approach:**

Let Event $A$ is "Not all the targets in group is detected"

And Event $B$ denotes "All the targets has been detected"

$\implies$$P(A)=1-P(B)$

According to question $p$ is probability that radar will detect targets $\implies$ $1-p$ will be Probability that radar will not detect target. So none of the radar will detect target is ${(1-p)^m}$. $\implies$ At least one radar will detect target is $1-(1-p)^m$.

$\implies$ At least one radar will detect the all the $k$ targets is $(1-(1-p)^m)^k$.

$\implies$ $P(B)=(1-(1-p)^m)^k$.

$\implies$ $P(A)=1-(1-(1-p)^m)^k$

**My doubt:**$(1)$ Is my Approach correct?

$(2)$ Can somebody suggest me All the other method to solve this Problem?

Answer (score 3):

Every target will be aimed at $m$ times,

so P(a particular target is *not* hit) $= (1-p)^m$

P(a particular target *is* hit) $= 1 - (1-p)^m$

P(all targets are hit) $=(1-(1-p)^m)^k$

P(at least one target not hit) = $1 - (1-(1-p)^m)^k$

So your approach is correct.